# How to order by dynamic column in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Columns]
(
    [ColumnId] INT,
    [TableId] INT NOT NULL,
    [ColumnName] NVARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    [Order] INT,
    [Key] BIT
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tables]
(
    [TableId] INT,
    [TableName] NVARCHAR(200)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RowValues]
(
    [ColumnId] INT NOT NULL,
    [RowNumber] INT NOT NULL,
    [Value] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)
```

With this sample data:

```
insert into [Columns] values (1, 1, 'StudentName', 1, 1)
insert into [Columns] values (2, 1, 'Grade', 1, 0)
insert into [Columns] values (3, 1, 'Year', 1, 0)
insert into [Columns] values (4, 1, 'Section', 1, 0)

insert into [Columns] values (5, 2, 'TeacherName', 1, 1)
insert into [Columns] values (6, 2, 'Department', 1, 0)

insert into [Tables] values (1, 'Student')
insert into [Tables] values (2, 'Teacher')

insert into [RowValues] values (1, 1, 'Student Alan')
insert into [RowValues] values (2, 1, '99')
insert into [RowValues] values (3, 1, '1st')
insert into [RowValues] values (4, 1, 'Section 1')

insert into [RowValues] values (1, 2, 'Student Alex')
insert into [RowValues] values (2, 2, '98')
insert into [RowValues] values (3, 2, '1st')
insert into [RowValues] values (4, 2, 'Section 1')

insert into [RowValues] values (1, 3, 'Student Alfonso')
insert into [RowValues] values (2, 3, '97')
insert into [RowValues] values (3, 3, '1st')
insert into [RowValues] values (4, 3, 'Section 1')

insert into [RowValues] values (1, 4, 'Student Ben')
insert into [RowValues] values (2, 4, '96')
insert into [RowValues] values (3, 4, '1st')
insert into [RowValues] values (4, 4, 'Section 1')

insert into [RowValues] values (1, 5, 'Student Cathy')
insert into [RowValues] values (2, 5, '95')
insert into [RowValues] values (3, 5, '1st')
insert into [RowValues] values (4, 5, 'Section 1')

insert into [RowValues] values (5, 1, 'Teacher Tesso')
insert into [RowValues] values (6, 1, 'Biology Dept')

insert into [RowValues] values (5, 2, 'Teacher Marvin')
insert into [RowValues] values (6, 2, 'Math Dept')
```

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_DynamicSearch_Paged]
    (@searchTerm NVARCHAR(max),
     @pageNumber INT = 1,
     @pageSize INT = 10,
     @sortColumn NVARCHAR(20),
     @sortDirection INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableNameLiteral nvarchar(13) = 'TableName'
    DECLARE @ColumnNameLiteral nvarchar(10) = 'ColumnName'

    IF (ISNULL(@sortColumn, '') = '')
    BEGIN
        SET @sortColumn = @TableNameLiteral
    END

    ;WITH KeyTableId AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            T.TableId
        FROM 
            [dbo].[Tables] T 
        INNER JOIN 
            [dbo].[Columns] C ON T.TableId = C.[TableId]
        WHERE
            C.[Key] = 1
    ), ColumnId AS
    (
        SELECT
            [KeyValue] = C.[ColumnName]
            ,[ColumnId] = V.[ColumnId]
            ,V.[Value]
            ,T.[TableName]
            ,C.[ColumnName]
            ,C.[Order]
            ,C.[Key]
        FROM 
            [dbo].[Tables] T 
        INNER JOIN 
            [dbo].[Columns] C ON T.TableId = C.[TableId]
        LEFT JOIN 
            [dbo].[RowValues] V ON V.[ColumnId] = C.[ColumnId]
        RIGHT JOIN 
            KeyTableId KT ON T.TableId = KT.TableId
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM ColumnId
    WHERE ISNULL(@SearchTerm,'') = ''
       OR [Value] LIKE @SearchTerm + '%'
    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 2 THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN @sortColumn = @TableNameLiteral THEN [TableName]
                WHEN @sortColumn = @ColumnNameLiteral THEN [ColumnName]
            END
        END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 1 THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN @sortColumn = @TableNameLiteral THEN [TableName]
                WHEN @sortColumn = @ColumnNameLiteral THEN [ColumnName]
            END
        END ASC
    OFFSET ((@pageNumber - 1) * @pageSize) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY; 


    SELECT 
        ColumnId = C.ColumnId,
        C.ColumnName,
        C.[Order],
        C.[Key]
    FROM [dbo].[Tables] T 
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Columns] C ON T.TableId = C.[TableId]


END
```

Based on the schema you can probably understand what I am trying to build.
My question is how do I order the result based on dynamic name

example (order by "StudentName" DESC)

Expected output

```
KeyValue        ColumnId    Value               TableName       ColumnName      Order   Key
'StudentName'       1       'Student Cathy'     'Student'       'StudentName'    1      1
'StudentName'       1       'Student Ben'       'Student'       'StudentName'    2      1
'StudentName'       1       'Student Alfonso'   'Student'       'StudentName'    3      1
'StudentName'       1       'Student Alex'      'Student'       'StudentName'    4      1
'StudentName'       1       'Student Alan'      'Student'       'StudentName'    5      1
'Grade'             2       '99'                'Student'       'Grade'          5      0   (Alan's Grade)
'Grade'             2       '98'                'Student'       'Grade'          4      0
... Year
... Section
...
```

How Do I sort by StudentName or Grade or Section or Year if key = student name

or

Sort by TeacherName or department if key = Teachername
indicated by @sortColumn NVARCHAR(20),

example

```
declare @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(max)=''
declare @pageNumber INT = 1
declare @pageSize INT = 10
declare @sortColumn NVARCHAR(20) ='StudentName'
declare @sortDirection int= 1 -- 0 asc 1 desc

exec [usp_DynamicSearch_Paged] @SearchTerm, @pageNumber, @pageSize, @sortColumn, @sortDirection
```

Comment: This looks like the real problem is your design. Why are you forcing yourself down a dynamic SQL and EAV path?

Comment: It is what is required. The student and teacher is just example data. Ofc I could have just created a get student and getteacher example if that was the case so I needed it to be dynamic

Comment: So the requirements dictate a completely denormalised design?

Comment: I guess so. I am thinking of building a dynamic sql string and using EXECUTE sp_executesql

Comment: I feel like it would really help if you share the requirements you have been given, as I see no *good* reason to design your database like this.

Comment: Suggested reading: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: I am aware of the pitfalls. It just needs to be this way

Comment: *"It just needs to be this way"* Why? What is mandating this design? Clearly it's a problem as you are already having difficulties. Imagine trying to maintain this when you're struggling to write a simple query.

Comment: your sort direction 0/1 but in code 1/2